# Get height of elements and apply largest number to smallest element(s)

Tags: javascript

I have a 3 column card layout. Information in a card is dynamically adjusted, and sometimes there is less info in one card vs the next. I equalized these boxes with vanilla JS, but I'm thinking there must be a more elegant way to solve this ([JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/zke235vy/)):

```
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.event-link .content');

if (!boxes.length) return;

let highest = 0;

for (let box of boxes) {
    const boxHeightStyle = getComputedStyle(box).height;
    const boxHeight = parseInt(boxHeightStyle);

    if (boxHeight > highest) {
        highest = boxHeight;
    }
}

for (let box of boxes) {
    const boxHeightStyle = getComputedStyle(box).height;
    const boxHeight = parseInt(boxHeightStyle);

    if (boxHeight < highest) {
        box.style.height = `${highest}px`;
    }
}
```

I separated two loops because in the first one I am only finding the highest pixel height, to then apply that highest number to the smallest element in the second loop.

Can this be combined?

Comment: *Can this be combined?* Shorter does not always mean better. It is better to have code which is easy to comprehend and to maintain.

Comment: You could skip one loop by adding a class to all elements in the first loop and after just enforce the height with that class.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going a flexbox approach, where you would set some content in your cards to flex-grow to fill up remaining space, and they should fill up the space given by the container their in. If not, give a max height based on either the content (checked in your js) or an arbitrary one you would know based on your content.